# TOR Ubuntu network PROXY setting for chrome

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy, tor

I have seen [this](https://miloserdov.org/?p=2062) post and **want to use tor Proxy setting in my chrome browser**, so for find local Ip and checking the IP the network proxy used this site:

https://suip.biz/?act=myip

And by the above instruction form [that](https://miloserdov.org/?p=2062) site, i have inserted this setting:

[image]

Also i have this option in the carburetor :

[image]

but it is not working for me one **chrome browser** and also i have tried this setting also :

[image]

also have two tor icon in my Ubuntu search results like this:

[image]

which i think it is because of this second tor manually installed like this:

[image]

current Ubuntu version is :

```
(base) so@so-notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

So what can i do?

thanks.

Comment: You do know that Tor Browser needs to be running in order for it to be available as a proxy on port 9050? Please try to describe exactly what you are trying to achieve, and what results you are getting.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: The only thing you should have to do is set 127.0.0.1 port 9050 as SOCKS5 proxy in your Chrome settings, nothing else. All those other settings might interfere with what you want to do.